# Possible unhandled promise rejection in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm using following code which produce "Possible unhandled promise rejection":

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)

    DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getItems(function (items) {
            console.log(items)//successfully print data
            this.setState({inventoryArray: items}).bind(this)//causing error
        })
}
```

Though, following code runs successfully and prints response in log:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getItems(function (items) {
            console.log(items)//Successfully print data
        })
    }
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, its a bad idea to make asynchronous calls in the `constructor` of the component. Instead, I would recommend that you make these calls from the `componentDidMount` as follows

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getItems(function (items) {
        console.log(items)//Successfully print data
        this.setState({ inventoryArray: items });
    });
  }
}
```

> More about how to use the `constructor` [in the official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

Answer (score 1):

You could also remove `bind` and use arrow function so `this` keeps the context in your component.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getItems((items) => {
    console.log(items)//successfully print data
    this.setState({inventoryArray: items})
  })
}
```

Also, your `.bind(this)` is in the wrong place. It should be placed in the outer `}` (where you close `function`)

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getItems(function (items) {
    console.log(items)
    this.setState({inventoryArray: items})
  }.bind(this)) // bind should come here
}
```

Making api requests in the constructor is a bad pattern though. 
[ReactJS Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) mentions that `componentDidMount` is the recommended place to do so.

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      inventoryArray: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getItems((items) => {
      console.log(items)//successfully print data
      this.setState({inventoryArray: items})
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making following changes solved this issue:

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.onGetInventories = this.onGetInventories.bind(this)

        //Loading inventory list from server
        DatabaseHandler.getInstance().getItems(this.onGetInventories)
    }


    onGetInventories(items) {
        console.log(items)
        this.setState({inventoryArray: items})//Works
    }
```